# m3u8 file contains cleaned files

Tags: nginx, rtmp

I configure nginx rtmp as follow

```
rtmp { 
    server { 
        listen 1935; 
        application live { 
            live on; 
            interleave on;
 
            hls on; 
            hls_path /mnt/hls; 
            hls_fragment 1s;
        } 
    } 
}
```

My `.m3u8` file contains `.ts` files that cleaned up , is it wrong?

i.e currently `50.ts` is generating and `45.ts` - `50.ts` is existing , but `.m3u8` file indexed `40.ts` - `50.ts`

Comment: how are you getting the stream?
what is the number of segments you want to keep?